# Can I still use Xamarin.Forms template even if I can't use Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a complete application that was written specifically for Android, using Xamarin.Android. Recently, our scope changed to also include a version for iOS and for Windows.

I was reading that converting my Xamarin.Android for Xamarin.Forms may not always be desirable especially if I have a bunch of custom UI layouts, which I do. Given the critical nature of our UI and layouts, I am okay with creating UI designs for each platform and just sharing the core logic.

However, I must admit that I know very little about Xamarin.Forms. I did create a new project for Xamarin.Forms and I like that it gave me a template already for all for all of the platforms (ie Droid, iOS, WinPhone 8.1 and Windows Universal).

What I do know about Xamarin.Forms is that you try to share not only the Logic but also the UI by doing most of your code and layout (xaml) in the shared forms class.

That said, can I just use this template that was created for me but instead do most of my work in each of the platform projects? I understand this means I will be duplicating some code and that I need to write the UI for each platform. I am okay with that and don't see a way around it given our design.

If this is the case, I assume that I can pretty much just copy all of my UI layouts and resources for Android into the new Android project created for me by the Forms project. Then I also am thinking I need to break out all of my logic from the Xamarin.Android project into seperate projects as portable class libraries and then just reference them from each of the platform classes? Is that correct? Is that how I would still share the logic but create a UI for each platform?

Help and guidance is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: if you're not going to use XF, the XF templates are of little use to you.  Instead just create a PCL project and begin refactoring your core app logic into it.  Then create new platform project, build their UI, and wire them up to use the logic in the PCL.

Comment: Thank Jason, I ended up taking your advice except instead of PCL, I am using shared projects.